# How to pbuilder build only certain .deb pacakges

Tags: packaging, development, pbuilder

So when I do a `pbuilder build *.dsc`, it builds every package in the dsc package list. Is it safe to edit the .dsc file's package list to contain only the desired packages. Or is there a way to be able to specify which packages pbuilder should build? I just want to reduce how long it takes since I need just a few of the `.deb`s that are produced.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution here is to specify the `.dsc` files you want to build, rather than all of them.

Using an asterisk will match *all* `.dsc` files.  Note that ALL packages inside a source package will be produced by the build system, this is a limitation of how debian packages are built and you cannot nitpick specific binaries form a source package to be built, as all the build rules and packages in a `debian/control` file for declaration and such are followed during build time and produced.